# Error while publishing Java EE application to WebSphere Server v8.5.5 in Eclipse. "The name parameter cannot be null"

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, websphere, publishing

When I want to publish my Java EE application to WebSphere server i get a following error:
[image: Error screenshot]

Server configuration seems to be ok - server status is displayed.

Same application deployed on Tomcat works just fine.

Any ideas what could be causing this problem?

Using:

- Eclipse LUNA SR2 IEE
- IBM WebSphere Application Server V8.5X Developer Tools for Eclipse Luna

Comment: You probably have some errors in descriptros. Did you try to clean/build application and run validation. See if you have any errors in the Markers view for your project.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem running Eclipse as Administrator.

Answer (score 0):

You have to allow the applications containing errors to be published on a server check box. you can do it in following manner:- (Windows > Preferences > Servers > WebSphere).

If this does not work, it is possible that you have build path error.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you set up your application server. I managed to resolve this issue by setting up a new Application Server from the WebSphere Customization Toolbox.

Launch the toolbox from the Start menu and create a new profile by selecting Application Server, and then complete settings intuitively, and start the server.

Connect to that server in your RAD, deploy the app and it will work like magic.

I don't know why, but this nasty problem occurs when I tried to use the application server that comes with deployment manager installation or any server from customized profile.